# How do I save uploaded binary files in a Perl FastCGI program?

Tags: perl, upload, fastcgi

My upload function looks like:

```
sub Upload_File{
my ($file, $mime, $description) = @_;
my $file_name   = param('filename');

my $data;

$file = UnTaint($file);

    if ($mime =~ /text/) {
            sysopen(VAULT, "$path/$file", O_RDWR | O_EXCL | O_CREAT | O_TEXT) or die "couldn't create $file for R/W: $!\n"; }
    else {
            sysopen(VAULT, "$path/$file", O_RDWR | O_EXCL | O_CREAT | O_BINARY) or die "couldn't create $file for R/W: $!\n";
    }

    my $upfh = \*VAULT;
    flock $upfh, 2;
    seek $upfh, 0, 0;
    select((select($upfh), $| = 1)[0]);
    while( sysread($file_name, $data, 8192) ) {
            syswrite($upfh, $data, 8192) or die "couldn't write $upfh: $!\n";
    }

    close $upfh; }
```

When I am using [read](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) and [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) with FastCGI upload script, files uploaded with corruptions (including simple text files), this is because `perl` uses buffered I/O. But when I use [syswrite](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html) and [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) i.e. non-buffered I/O, as a result I get good text files, but binary files are corrupted anyway.

Comment: Could you tell what libraries you're using? And are you using strict and warnings?

Comment: use CGI::Fast qw(:standard);
use strict;
use encoding 'utf8';
use FCGI::ProcManager;
use File::Basename;
use DBD::SQLite;
use Fcntl;
use POSIX;

and yes, i'm using warnings.

Comment: Problem was in use encoding 'utf8'. After i remove it, all files uploads without corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing some confusion regarding `$file` and `$file_name`. The latter is either wrongly named or wrongly used.

Further, this sounds to me like a [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) problem. You may want to call [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on your input filehandle.

As a further hint, you could open your files as `sysopen(my $upfh, ...`. And seek is buffered, so if you're using [syswrite](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html) (I wouldn't) then you can better use [sysseek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysseek.html).

Comment: Thanks,
i'm try to use sysseek, but it does not helps me.

and yes $file and $file_name wrongly named, but works fine.

after adding binmode(VAULT) in if-else statement, right after sysopen, there is no changes. 

some expirements show me, that text files corrupts too, when they are quite big. 
i add $CGI::POST_MAX=1024 * 10000, but it does not helps.